# Bootstrap Navbar change when scroll down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using the Carousel template to make my thing. And I what that the navbar change when i scroll down.
When the caroussel is on the screen it stays with the navbar detached from the top, centered, and when i scrolldown, it changes to 'navbar-fixed-top'.

Here is a good example...
http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-grayscale/

Comment: look up the bootstrap affix and then mix it up with css transitions

Comment: Hi ZetCoby, Thank you for your help. I will try that. Then I let you know the result... :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i understand but if you want that your navbar doesn't stay fixed to the top when you scroll down you have to remove the class:

```
    navbar-fixed-top
```

from the nav element. I think that you have this class in your code actually.

Comment: Hi Roberto, Is the oposite. If you look into de caroussel template ( http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/ ) you see the navbar is not fixed. If you scroll down she desapear... What i want is that when you scroll down, the navbar changes to a fixed position on top.

Comment: Ok i got it now, i'm sorry. Maybe this can be a solution for you? [link](http://www.bootply.com/69848)